# How to access host machine details inside the docker container

Tags: docker

Using docker container to run one of our applications, required to send the host system information to the cloud, I would like to know the way to get host machine details especially the MAC address from inside the Docker container.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can approach this problem different way. Eg. pass information you need from host to container via environment variables.

```
docker run -e HOST_MAC=$(ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K.*$') image
```

This requires you to change how you run a container, however it's probably the cleanest method of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your host system, since you didn't give any information I'm just going to assume CentOS

In this [article](http://vaunaspada.babel.it/blog/?p=415) it shows how you can get that info from /prove on the host system. So, if you mount /prove into your container you should be able to read the right file and pull out your info.

This doesn't seem secure though, and I recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options.

Аnother option is

```
docker run -it -v /var/log/:/log --name vmaccess busybox /bin/sh
grep eth0 /log/dmesg

[    2.307760] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 08:00:27:98:dc:aa
[    2.307783] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    4.186427] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    8.985277] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to use `--net=host` while starting the container.

`$# ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K.*$'`

```
00:00:00:00:00:00  
9c:b6:54:1d:80:4b  
48:5a:b6:67:9e:11
```

`$# docker run --net=host -it ubuntu:14.04 bash`

`$# ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K.*$'`

```
00:00:00:00:00:00  
9c:b6:54:1d:80:4b  
48:5a:b6:67:9e:11
```